# python struct unpack bad char

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I am trying to write a small package parser, first time using python struct for it:

```
content = struct.unpack("BBBBBB<HBB", packet[:10])
```

packet contains the following bytes:

```
7e03 ffff ff0f 1e00 1001 0c00 0000 0000
```

I get this error: `struct.error: bad char in struct format` but I have no clue how I should know whats the bad char mentioned. Also on that note: does struct support grouping tuple elements, because I would rather have the unpacking done like this:

```
content = struct.unpack("BB(BBBB)<HBB", packet[:10])
```

Because this is an address, and having it inside its own tuple in content would it make cleaner imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` can't be in the middle of the format string, it needs to be at the front.

It specifies little-endian byte order and applies to the whole packet (but it makes no difference for single-byte values like those specified with `B`):

```
>>> packet = b'\x7e\x03\xff\xff\xff\x0f\x1e\x00\x10\x01\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack("<BBBBBBHBB", packet[:10])
(126, 3, 255, 255, 255, 15, 30, 16, 1)
```

To interpret four bytes as one unsigned integer, use `I` or `L`:

```
>>> struct.unpack("<BBIHBB", packet[:10])
(126, 3, 268435455, 30, 16, 1)
```

Comment: ok, fortunately I do not need mixed little and big endian thanks. That did not really come through in the docs I searched.